# Add a track to spotify playlist using spotify-api-server

Tags: php, terminal, spotify, playlist

I've asked the owner for the project for some help, but thought I'd ask stack overflow as well.

Does anyone know how to correctly add a track using the spotify-api-server? I'm sure i'm missing something simple:

Could you please tell me how to POST and add a track to a playlist? I keep getting an error no matter what I try. If i try and POST the URI as detailed in the readme, it errors:

```
["spotify:track:1lDWb6b6ieDQ2xT7ewTC3G"]

error: {"message":"Invalid input"}
```

---

```
["1lDWb6b6ieDQ2xT7ewTC3G"]

error: {"message":"No valid tracks"}
```

```

If I try and POST to `localhost:1337/playlist/{playlist ID}/add?index` I get the error `{"message":"Bad parameter: index must be numeric"}`. It's only after changing `index` to `index=1` does it let me move on and attempt to add a track. Is this correct?

I'm doing this through PHP, but happy to see terminal commands that I can try out and then adapt.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding `{"message":"Bad parameter: index must be numeric"}`, yes, that's correct — that's the index at which the track will be inserted into the playlist. `0` will make it the first item.